# Magento2 use backend setting to apply custom layout in module

Tags: magento2, layout, backend

I have written a module that has a settings page in the backend.
The Module overrides a layout.xml file and uses a modified template by editing my own template path

```
view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml
```

in this line of the layout file:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="form/register.phtml">
```

But I would like to override this layout file only if the backend settings for this module is set to enabled.

I know I can add some code in the template I override to check for the setting before doing my modifications, but is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **`ifconfig`** attribute to check admin setting,

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="form/register.phtml" ifconfig="passyour/config/value">
```

For your reference in wishlist module,

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active" name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to view template only if your module is enabled from backend :

```
<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="tagname/general/active">
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="form/register.phtml">
</action>
```